# Filter & RequestDispatcher to change URL effect on existing filters

Tags: servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

I have made a filter that is responsible for adding `.do` to requests and is the first declared filter:

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if(! (request instanceof  HttpServletRequest)){
      chain.doFilter(request, response );
    }

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String requestUrl = httpServletRequest.getServletPath();

    if(!isBetaPathRequest(httpServletRequest) || StringUtils.contains(requestUrl,".")){
      chain.doFilter(request, response );
      return;
    }

    String newUrl = requestUrl;

    int lastIndexOf = requestUrl.lastIndexOf("?");
    if(lastIndexOf == -1){

      if(requestUrl.charAt(requestUrl.length()-1) != '/'){
        newUrl = newUrl.concat(".do");
      }

    }
    else{
      newUrl = requestUrl.substring(0, lastIndexOf-1) .concat(".do")  .concat(requestUrl.substring(lastIndexOf));
    }

    final RequestDispatcher rq = getRequestDispatcher(request, newUrl);
    rq.forward(request, response);
  }
```

There are other various filters also declared in the project `web.xml` file and I am notificing with the debugger that they are not being run.

The current mapping for one important filter is for example:

ContentResponseCachingFilter
    *.do

But the initial incoming request does not include `.do` in the URl until it passed through the `BetaRewriteUrlFilter`.

When RequestDispatcher.forward is called, are the filters applied or do we need to manually cal them or instead use a 302 redirect???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to place this new filter last in the web.xml definiton.

This rewrite filter needed to be last on the chain, since using the `request dispatcher` `forward` method would not break functionallity or inhibit the running of the other filters.